# Comparing multiple control with single validation in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have five Dropdowns containing same values **e.g** **"Number from 1 to 10"** in my page. I want a **User** to **select different value in each Dropdown**. How can I validate all of five controls to check different values from each other.

Compare field Validator is only for comparing to controls. How to compare multiple controls?

Thanks

Comment: you would have to write a custom validator

Comment: Why not just use `CheckBoxList` instead of 5 Dropdowns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CustomValidator with JavaScript function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction(v=vs.110).aspx) for validation. Note that I assumed your ddl options will have `Value` attributes set to 0,1,2..so on. 0 for 'Select' option. `Text` attributes can be anything.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server">
   <asp:ListItem Text="Number from 1 to 3" Value="0" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

If you can transform below code to jQuery, it will be much smaller than this plain JS version.

```
var valid = false;
var ddlValues = ''; // selected values of lists
var separator = '~';
var ddlOptions;
var ddls = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

for (var i = 0; i < ddls.length; i++) {
    if (ddls[i].value == '0') { // No option selected for this list.
        valid = false;
        break;
    }
    if (i == 0) { ddlOptions = ddls[i].options; }
    ddlValues += ddls[i].value + separator; // "1~2~1~"
    valid = true;
}

if (valid) {
    for (var i = 1; i < ddlOptions.length; i++) {
        var testValue = ddlOptions[i].value + separator;
        var regex = new RegExp(testValue, 'g');
        var replacedValues = ddlValues.replace(regex, '');
        if (ddlValues.length - replacedValues.length > testValue.length) {
            valid = false;
            break; // We found duplicate selection
        }
    }
}

return valid;
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can set all 5 dropdown id(for example : ddl1, ddl2 ... ddl5), and when selects one controls value you can compare the values with javascript or ajax.

```
$('#ddl1').onchange(myControlFunction);
$('#ddl2').onchange(myControlFunction);
$('#ddl3').onchange(myControlFunction);
$('#ddl4').onchange(myControlFunction);
$('#ddl5').onchange(myControlFunction);

var myControlFunction = function(){
var ddl1 = $('#ddl1').val();
var ddl2 = $('#ddl2').val();
var ddl3 = $('#ddl3').val();
var ddl4 = $('#ddl4').val();
var ddl5 = $('#ddl5').val();

if (CompareIsSame(ddl1, ddl2, ddl3, ddl4, ddl5))
    alert("Same value");
e.preventDefaults();
}
```

Comment: Most often, you cannot answer without showing some code, exceptions being conceptual question/answers. This is better suited as comment.